# Extending Hartl Rails Tutorial with user selected micropost feed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new to web development and Rails and have finished Hartl's tutorial. I am trying to extend the app with added links to home.html.erb to allow the user to select different micropost feeds on the home page and have the new feed display without reloading the page (using ajax and jquery). The three feeds are:

Community  - all microposts
My Friends - microposts for the user and his/her followers (same as final tutorial feed)
My Posts   - just the user's posts **** Fixed this one**

The only feed that works correctly is the My Friends feed (the one from the tutorial), for the other two, the @feed_items is nil causing the following error in the *.erb.js

I am tearing my hair out--thanks for any help! I have never used this site, so please let me know if I should add any info or if I have asked this incorrectly.

Started GET "/mycontributions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-12 06:10:12 -0500
Processing by StaticPagesController#userfeed as JS
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'fHe72EwO6387WdP26K07Rw' LIMIT 1
  SQL (112.2ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "feed_selection" = 'My Contributions' WHERE "users"."id" = 1
  Micropost Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE (user_id IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
 WHERE follower_id = 1) OR user_id = 1) ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "microposts" WHERE (user_id IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
 WHERE follower_id = 1) OR user_id = 1)
  Rendered static_pages/userfeed.js.erb (5.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 143ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `paginate' for nil:NilClass):
    1: alert ('start of userfeed.js.erb');
    2: $('#MyContributions').parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    3: <% @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build %>
    4: <% @feed_items = current_user.userfeed.paginate(page: params[:page]) %>
    5: $('.microposts').remove();
    6: $('.pagination').remove();
    7: $("#buzzFeed").append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shared/feed') %>");
  app/views/static_pages/userfeed.js.erb:4:in`_app_views_static_pages_userfeed_js_erb_*774602371*_641866188'

The links in home.html.erb:

```
<li class="<%= 'active' if current_user.feed_selection == 'Community Buzz' %>">
    <%= link_to 'Community Buzz', 
        { :controller => :static_pages, :action => :communityfeed }, 
        remote: true, id: 'CommunityBuzz', class: "buzz-cat"  %> 
</li>
<li class="<%= 'active' if current_user.feed_selection == 'My Friends' %>">
    <%= link_to "My Friends", 
        { :controller => :static_pages, :action => :friendfeed }, 
        remote: true, id: "MyFriends", class: "buzz-cat" %>
</li>
<li class="<%= 'active' if current_user.feed_selection == 'My Contributions' %>">
<%= link_to "My Contributions", 
        { :controller => :static_pages, :action => :userfeed }, 
        remote: true, id: "MyContributions", class: "buzz-cat" %>
</li>
```

The static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  def home
    puts "StaticPagesContoller: action: home: start method"
    if signed_in?
      puts "home signed-in - feed_selection is: " + current_user.feed_selection

      if current_user.feed_selection.nil?
        puts "home signed-in - feed_selection is nil, so default it to 'Community Buzz' in the database"
        current_user.update_column(:feed_selection, "Community Buzz")
        toggle_feed(current_user.feed_selection, "Community Buzz") if !current_user.feed_selection.nil?
        end

      puts "home, signed-in - before calling toggle_feed"
      toggle_feed(current_user.feed_selection, current_user.feed_selection) if !current_user.feed_selection.nil?
      puts "home, signed-in - after  calling toggle_feed"

    end
  end

  def communityfeed
    puts "StaticPagesContoller: action: communityfeed: start method"
    if signed_in?
      puts "communityfeed, signed-in - feed_selection is: " + current_user.feed_selection
      puts "communityfeed, signed-in - before calling toggle_feed"
      toggle_feed(current_user.feed_selection, "Community Buzz") if !current_user.feed_selection.nil?
      puts "communityfeed, signed-in - after  calling toggle_feed"
    end    
  end

  def friendfeed
    puts "StaticPagesContoller: action: friendfeed: start method"
    if signed_in?
    puts "friendfeed, signed-in - feed_selection is: " + current_user.feed_selection
    puts "friendfeed, signed-in - before calling toggle_feed"
    toggle_feed(current_user.feed_selection, "My Friends") if !current_user.feed_selection.nil?
    puts "friendfeed, signed-in - after  calling toggle_feed"

    end
  end

  def userfeed
    puts "StaticPagesContoller: action: userfeed: start method"
    if signed_in?
      puts "userfeed, signed-in - feed_selection is: " + current_user.feed_selection
      toggle_feed(current_user.feed_selection, "My Contributions") if !current_user.feed_selection.nil?     

    end
  end
end
```

toggle_feed is in application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper

 def toggle_feed(saved_feed_selection, picked_feed)    
    if saved_feed_selection != picked_feed
      puts "ApplicationController: toggle_feed: saved_feed_selection != picked_feed, saving picked_feed to database" 
      current_user.update_column(:feed_selection, picked_feed)       
      puts "ApplicationController: toggle_feed: after database save."
    end
    puts "ApplicationController: toggle_feed: before assigning @micropost"
    @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
    puts "ApplicationController: toggle_feed: after assigning @micropost = " + @micropost.to_s

    case picked_feed
    when "Community Buzz" then
      @feed_items = current_user.communityfeed.paginate(page: params[:page])
when "My Friends" then
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
when "My Contributions" then
      @feed_items = Micropost.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).paginate(page: params[:page])
    else
      puts "FAILED case!"
    end  
    puts "ApplicationController: toggle_feed: End"
  end 
end
```

The user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password #call this method to populate :password_digest field
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

#  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save { self.email.downcase! }
  before_save :create_remember_token # calls the private method (see below)

  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  def communityfeed
    puts "User.rb: communityfeed method: start"
    Micropost.all
    puts "User.rb: communityfeed method: end"
  end

  def feed # this is My Friends + the user
    Micropost.from_users_followed_by(self)
  end

  def userfeed # this is My Contributions
    puts "User.rb: userfeed method: start"
    Micropost.where("user_id = ?", id)
    puts "User.rb: userfeed method: end"
  end

  def following?(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id)
  end

  def follow!(other_user)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  def unfollow!(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id).destroy
  end       

  private

    def create_remember_token
      puts "executing 'create remember token'"
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end
```

This one works friendfeed.js.erb

```
alert ('start of friendfeed.js.erb');
$('#MyFriends').parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
<% @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build %>
<% @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page]) %>
$('.microposts').remove();
$('.pagination').remove();
$("#buzzFeed").append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shared/feed') %>");
alert ('end of friendfeed.js.erb');
```

This one doesn't work userfeed.js.erb

```
alert ('start of userfeed.js.erb');
$('#MyContributions').parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
<% @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build %>
<% @feed_items = Micropost.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).paginate(page: params[:page]) %>
$('.microposts').remove();
$('.pagination').remove();
$("#buzzFeed").append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shared/feed') %>");
alert ('end of userfeed.js.erb');
```

Comment: I am making some progress. I have solved the case when just the user's posts should be displayed by changing the feed_items = line in the userfeed.js.erb to the following: <% @feed_items = Micropost.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).paginate(page: params[:page]) %> and also making the corresponding change in toggle_feed on the ApplicationController. However, to fix the first case, I would just need to change the communityfeed.js.erb line to <% feed_items = Micropost.all.paginate(page: params[:page]) %>, but that does not work. Arg, any ideas?

Comment: I figured out the other case (displaying all microposts) but I don't understand why. To make it work I changed the feed_items in the communityfeed.js.erb and in toggle_feed in ApplicationController to be @feed_items = Micropost.paginate(page: params[:page]). Why didn't Micropost.all work?